# Problem parsing product `2\x` with `TiKZ 3.0`

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I was used to write `2\x` to obtain the product `2*x` but today I've found this is not correct anymore in `TiKZ`.

Next code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=0.5cm]
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} 
    \foreach \j in {0,...,3} {
        \draw[black] (\i,\j) circle[radius=2pt];
        \draw[blue] (2\i,2\j) circle[radius=2pt];
        \draw[red] (2*\i,2*\j) circle[radius=1pt];
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives me

[image]

As you can see all blue circles with coordinates computed through `(2\i, 2\j)` are wrongly placed while red ones computed with `(2*\i,2*\j)` are correct.

I don't remember to have read anything about `*` addition for products in `TiKZ` but, of course, I could be wrong. So, is it a known behaviour? Where is it documented?

Comment: I have always used `*` as otherwise it is just expanding to `2\i==20`, so I think it is obvious to always put the `*`. Think what would happen if you accidentally put it in an expanded context. Then `2\i` would always be wrong.

Comment: I think you were using `2\i` if `\i`  was a dimen. Then it is recognized but otherwise it should be as zeroth noted direct replacement of the number.

Comment: @percusse: thank you for the comment. Could you consider converting it into an answer?

Comment: Was it the problem?

Comment: @zeroth: After more than twenty years using LaTeX I'm still trying to understand `expansion`, so, thank you for the example. Please consider converting it into an answer?

Comment: @percusse: Probably yes. I've been looking for some wrong use (like mine) in pgfmanual and could'nt find it. So I start to think that my memory fails and always used expressions like `2\...` for dimensions and not inside coordinates computing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple reason for not using this is that TikZ expands its arguments whenever it can (in certain context it might not expand the macros):

```
\foreach \i in {0,1} {
   \draw (2\i,0) circle (2pt);
}
```

will produce these commands

```
\draw (20,0) circle (2pt);
\draw (21,0) circle (2pt);
```

it would then correspond to coordinates multiplied by the current `x` and `y` unit vectors (1cm is the default value for both) which was clearly not the intent.

Providing an asterisk (`*`) will enable the TikZ to switch to pgfmath parsing which then calculates the result

```
\foreach \i in {0,1} {
   (2*\i,0)
}
```

and will produce:

```
\draw (0,0) circle (2pt);
\draw (2,0) circle (2pt);
```

Alternatively, if the variable is a dimension, then left implied multiplication is a valid TeX operation such as `.5\textwidth,2\pageheight` etc. Then Tikz reads the dimension calculation as a single argument and expands correctly.

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify some minor differences. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @percusse, sure no problem :)